# Are mission rewards added in the July 30, 2013 patch rewarded to players that have completed the associated missions?

Tags: spiral-knights

Per the title, I want to know if the new items available from July 30 onwards will be retroactively rewarded to veteran players that have completed these older missions.  I scanned the patch notes and they don't seem to mention this, and I'm sure other returning players would like to know how to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, players that have completed missions that reward new items will also receive these items.  Upon login, the player will receive a single piece of mail containing all retroactive mission rewards.  You can [check the wiki](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/List_of_missions) for details as to specific mission rewards, but the mail I received contained many items relating to the new Battle Sprites, various heating items, orbs of alchemy, and sparks of life.

**Edit:** I apparently missed this announcement in the patch notes, as they stuck it at the very bottom of a long list of items.  Here's the quote...

> **Rarity Distribution to Existing Players**
>
> All existing players have been sent rarities based on their current Mission Rank. Each player will receive exactly the total number of rarities they would have otherwise received from missions as of this update. All items are bound.